# Interface, Configuration and Endpoint are these software entity or hardware

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand Linux USB Device drivers, most of the documentation speaks about the USB Device decoded into

- configuration
- interface
- Endpoint

Linux only supports one configuration. Are these hardware entities or simply data present in the driver of the data which it passes on USB Device detection

Answer (score 1):

When referring to a USB device, the terms "configuration", "interface", and "endpoint", are all properties of the device.  They can be changed if you are able to reprogram the device, but if not then you can just think of them as part of the hardware.

The device has binary chunks of data called "descriptors" which the computer fetches so the computer can know what configurations, interfaces, and endpoints the device has.

You can learn all about those items and their descriptors by reading the USB 2.0 specification:

https://usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification